# C++: Constructor accepting only a string literal

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, string-literals

Is it possible to create a constructor (or function signature, for that matter) that *only* accepts a string literal, but not an e.g. `char const *`?

Is it possible to have two overloads that can distinguish between string literals and `char const *`?

C++ 0x would kind-of allow this with a custom suffix - but I'm looking for an "earlier" solution.

**Rationale:** avoiding heap copy of strings that won't be modified when given as string literals.

These strings directly go to an API expecting a `const char *` without any processing. Most calls do use literals requiring no additional processing, only in a few cases they are constructed.  I am looking for a possibility to preserve the native call behavior.

**Note:** - since it comes up in the answers: the code in question does not use `std::string` at all, but a good example would be:

```
class foo
{
   std::string m_str;
   char const * m_cstr;      
 public:
   foo(<string literal> s) : m_cstr(p) {}
   foo(char const * s) : m_str(s) { m_cstr = s.c_str(); }
   foo(std::string const & s) : m_str(s) { m_cstr = s.c_str(); }

   operator char const *() const { return m_cstr; }
}
```

---

**Results:**

(1) it can't be done.
(2) I realized I am not even looking for a literal, but for a compile-time-constant (i.e. "anything that needs not be copied").

I will probably use the following pattern instead:

```
const literal str_Ophelia = "Ophelia";

void Foo()
{
  Hamlet(str_Ophelia, ...);  // can receive literal or string or const char *
}
```

with a simple

```
struct literal  
{ 
   char const * data; 
   literal(char const * p) : data(p) {} 
   operator const char *() const { return data; }
};
```

That doesn't stop anyone from abusing it (I should find a better name...), but it allows the required optimization but remains safe by default.

Comment: I don't think so, since `string` has a constructor that takes a `char const *`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the rationale? I can't quite see why you would wish to copy a string literal, but NOT copy a 'const char *' (or the other way around). You aren't allowed to change both in exactly the same way.

Comment: You will also have to maintain a flag and have conditional code in your destructor. It seems you would have to create  a lot more objects using string literals than I usually do to make this worthwhile.

Comment: @Neil: I'm stumbling over this pattern repeatedly, in different scenarios. I agree that in most places, the copy doesn't matter - but when writing libraries, you don't know if you are called 10 times or 10 million times.

Comment: @ypnpos: the question is: can the initial copy into a std::string be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version updated for C++20 based on [ansiwen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3750161/ansiwen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296962).

Note that just like that answer this method isn't perfect. The last examples in the code will be interpreted as literals even though they are not. So runs the risk of UB.

But should be pretty rare since there's not much reason to create a const char array as that has few benefits over a string literal. We had no cases of this in our code.

```
#include <iostream>

#define LITERAL std::cout << "literal" << std::endl
#define NON_LITERAL std::cout << "char array" << std::endl

template <typename T>
concept IsCharStar = std::is_same_v<T, char*> || std::is_same_v<T, const char*>;

struct Foo {
    template<int N> Foo(const char (&)[N]) { LITERAL; }
    template<int N> Foo(char (&)[N]) { NON_LITERAL; }
    template<int N> Foo(const char (&&)[N]) { NON_LITERAL; }
    template<int N> Foo(char (&&)[N]) { NON_LITERAL; }
    template<IsCharStar T> Foo(T) { NON_LITERAL; }
};

char gchararray[] = "x";
const char* gcharstar = "x";
Foo f1() { return "hello"; }
Foo f2() { return gchararray; }
Foo f3() { return gcharstar; }
Foo f4() { char buffer[10] = "lkj"; return buffer; }
Foo f5() { const char buffer[10] = "lkj"; return buffer; }

int main() {
    char buf[10] = "buffer";
    char* charstar = "char star";
    Foo v1("x");       // literal
    Foo v2(buf);       // char array
    Foo v3(charstar);  // char array
    f1();              // literal
    f2();              // char array
    f3();              // char array
    f4();              // char array

    // But note that it's not perfect
    const char buf2[15] = "const buffer";
    Foo v4(buf2);      // literal
    f5();              // literal, will result UB
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Working solution based on [sbi idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041355/c-constructor-accepting-only-a-string-literal/2041408#2041408):

```
struct char_wrapper
{
    char_wrapper(const char* val) : val(val) {};
    const char* val;
};

class MyClass {
public:
  template< std::size_t N >
  explicit MyClass(const char (&str)[N])
  {
      cout << "LITERAL" << endl;
  }
  template< std::size_t N >
  explicit MyClass(char (&str)[N])
  {
      cout << "pointer" << endl;
  }    
  MyClass(char_wrapper m)
  {
     cout << "pointer" << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass z("TEST1");     // LITERAL
    const char* b = "fff";
    MyClass a(b);           // pointer
    char tmp[256]; 
    strcpy(tmp, "hello"); 
    MyClass c(tmp);         // pointer
}
```

Comment: Probably the fact that it doesn't work - it recognises character arrays as string literals for a start.

Comment: nonetheless, goo idea for working around the overload resolution problem.

Comment: +1:  Its not possible to differentiate between "const char []" and a string literal, so this is the optimal solution.

Comment: In C++03 you can keep them apart by checking whether they convert to both `char*` and `const char[]`: If they do, it's a string literal, if they don't, it's a plain array. But in C++0x, they removed the deprecated conversion from a string literal to `char*`, thus this hack won't work anymore then :)

Comment: @Johannes:  That's a use of that particular conversion I'm sure nobody ever envisaged!

Answer (score 20):

Yes, it **can** be done! I came up with a solution that works with C++03 and without a wrapper class (which breaks some implicit conversions in return statements).

First of all, you need a constructor template for the types `const char (&)[N]`, since this is the original type of string literals. Then you also need another one for the types `char (&)[N]` - like char buffers for instance - so that they con't end up in the constructor for literals. And probably you also want a normal constructor for the type `const char*`.

```
template<int N> Foo(const char (&)[N]); // for string literals
template<int N> Foo(char (&)[N]);       // for non-const char arrays like buffers
Foo(const char*);                       // normal c strings
```

The problem now is, that for string literals the compiler still thinks, that the `const char*` constructor is a better choice than a template instance, since *array-to-pointer conversions* have *exact-match rank*. (13.3.3.1.1)

So, the trick is to lower the precedence of the `const char*` constructor. This can be done by changing it to a template as well and using SFINAE to match it only against the type `const char*`. The constructor has no return value and only one parameter, that is necessary for type deduction. Therefore another "dummy parameter" with default value is necessary, that uses the conditional type trait: `template<typename T> Foo(T, typename IsCharPtr<T>::Type=0)`

**Solution:**

```
#include <iostream>

#define BARK std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl

struct Dummy {};
template<typename T> struct IsCharPtr {};
template<> struct IsCharPtr<const char *> { typedef Dummy* Type; };
template<> struct IsCharPtr<char *> { typedef Dummy* Type; };

struct Foo {
  template<int N> Foo(const char (&)[N]) { BARK; }
  template<int N> Foo(char (&)[N]) { BARK; }
  template<typename T> Foo(T, typename IsCharPtr<T>::Type=0) { BARK; }
};

const char a[] = "x";
const char* b = "x";
const char* f() { return b; }

int main() {
  char buffer[10] = "lkj";
  char* c = buffer;
  Foo l("x");     // Foo::Foo(const char (&)[N]) [N = 2]
  Foo aa(a);      // Foo::Foo(const char (&)[N]) [N = 2]
  Foo bb(b);      // Foo::Foo(T, typename IsCharPtr<T>::Type) [T = const char *]
  Foo cc(c);      // Foo::Foo(T, typename IsCharPtr<T>::Type) [T = char *]
  Foo ee(buffer); // Foo::Foo(char (&)[N]) [N = 10]
  Foo ff(f());    // Foo::Foo(T, typename IsCharPtr<T>::Type) [T = const char *]
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the valid answer.

Comment: What if one const_cast's a char buffer? Then I believe that template<int N> Foo(const char (&)[N]) { BARK; } will be used.

Comment: A common pattern is to pass const class ref to methods.  If the class has a non-const char array member it will 'inherit' the const from the parameter ref.  If the member is passed to Foo::Foo() it will use Foo::Foo( const char (&)[] ), which will think it's a literal but in fact isn't.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when a char-array is used in return position. Something like `Foo returnsFoo() { char buffer[10] = "abc"; return buffer }` ends up calling the `Foo::Foo(const char (&)[N])` constructor.

To fix this you also need to add:
`template<int N> Foo(char (&&)[N]) { BARK; }`
and possibly also one for `const char(&&)`

Answer (score 8):

No, you just can't do this - string literals and const char* are interchangeable. One workaround could be to introduce a special class to hold pointers to string literals and make a constructor only accepting that. This way whenever you need to pass a literal you call a constructor of that class and pass the temporary object. This doesn't completely prevent misuse, but makes code much more maintainable.

Comment: Is this still true for C++14? Hmm, maybe user defined literals could be used? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly how your compiler and platform deal with string literals, it might be possible to write a solution that can do this.  If you know that your compiler always puts string literals into a specific region of memory, you can check the pointer against the bounds of that memory.  If it falls within that block, you've got a string literal; otherwise you've got a string stored on the heap or stack.

However, this solution would be platform/compiler-specific.  It would not be portable.

Comment: probably the only "safe" way to do that, but I don't want to rely on that much unportable trickery. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On some platforms, I have had to declare string literals as `static const char *` in order for the program to access the text from Read-Only Memory.  When declared as `const char *`, the assembly listing showed that the text was copied from ROM onto a stack variable.

Instead of worrying about the receiver, perhaps try declaring the string literals with `static const char *`.

Answer (score 1):

With a new user-defined literals in C++14 (as for Clang 3.5 - it works with C++11 too), there is an elegant solution:

```
class Literal {
 public:
  explicit Literal(const char* literal) : literal_(literal) {}
  // The constructor is public to allow explicit conversion of external string
  // literals to `_L` literals. If there is no such need, then move constructor
  // to private section.

  operator const char* () { return literal_; }

 private:
  friend Literal operator"" _L (const char*, unsigned long);
  // Helps, when constructor is moved to private section.

  const char* literal_;
};

Literal operator"" _L (const char* str, unsigned long) {
  return Literal(str);
}
```

It may be used like this:

```
void f1(Literal) {}  // Accepts literals only.

int main() {
  auto str1 = "OMG! Teh Rey!"_L;
  std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
  f(str1);
}
```

There is one drawback: you have to append `_L` to every literal - but it's not a big deal, really.